# Scraping pages of websites using Apify's Puppetteer Crawler

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer, cheerio, apify

### **(*) Situation :**

Hello There !

I want to scrape [google hotels platform](https://www.google.com/travel/hotels) , I tap a city , and It will give me all hotels in that city.
for example the result for [New York City](https://www.google.com/travel/hotels?utm_campaign=sharing&utm_medium=link&utm_source=htls&hrf=CgUI7gUQACIDTUFEKhYKBwjkDxAIGB0SBwjkDxAIGB4YASgAsAEAWAFoAZoBMRIITmV3IFlvcmsaJTB4ODljMjRmYTVkMzNmMDgzYjoweGM4MGI4ZjA2ZTE3N2ZlNjKqAQoKAgghEgIIFRgB&rp=SAI&destination=New%20York&ap=MABoAA) , it will give us more than 1200 hotels , so I want to scrape all informations about these hotels.

I used Apify's Puppeteer Crawler , in ***starts urls*** , I put the url of the first page .
in ***Link selector*** , I put the selector to go to the hotels details page .

This is what I put in ***Page Function*** :

```js
async function pageFunction(context) {
    
    const { request, log, skipLinks, page } = context;
   

    //request.userData = list_links;
    if (request.userData.label === 'START') {
        log.info('Store opened!');
       
    }

    if (request.userData.label === 'DETAIL') {
        const { url } = request;
        log.info(`Scraping ${url}`);
        await skipLinks();
        
        const titleP = page.$eval(
            'title',
            (el => el.textContent)
        );
       const priceP = page.$eval(
           'div.JGa7fd',
           (el => el.getAttribute('aria-label'))
       );
        const ratingP = page.$eval(
            'div.iDqPh.BgYkof',
            (el => el.textContent)
        );
        const reviewsNumberP = page.$eval(
            'a.eS7K5e',
            (el => el.textContent)
        );
        const hotelStarP = page.$eval(
            'div.fnmyY > span.CFH2De',
            (el => el.textContent)
        );
        const adressP = page.$$eval(
           'div.K4nuhf span.CFH2De',
           (els) => els[0].textContent
       ); 
       
        const phoneP = page.$$eval(
            'div.K4nuhf span.CFH2De',
            (els) => els[2].textContent

        );
        const websiteP = page.$$eval(
            'a.FKF6mc.TpQm9d',
            (els) => els[0].getAttribute('href')
        );

        
        const [
            title,
            price,
            rating,
            reviewsNumber,
            adress,
            phone,
            hotelStar,
            website,
            
        ] = await Promise.all([
            titleP,
            priceP,
            ratingP,
            reviewsNumberP,
            adressP,
            phoneP,
            hotelStarP,
            websiteP,
        ]);

    
        

        return {
            title,
            price,
            rating,
            reviewsNumber,
            adress,
            phone,
            hotelStar,
            website,
        };
    }
}
```

### **(*) Problem :**

if you analyse the pages , you will see that they're not enumerated pages (page 1,page 2 , page 3) , we have just Next & Previous Button (even if when you analyse the URL , it hasn't "&page=1/2/3 " or something like that , and if we expect this button (next button) ,  we will get that it'is a div tag with role="button" , and without any href attribute to select .

## **(*) Question :**

**1-** How to scrape all pages using Puppeteer ? How to go to next pages and **scrape** them ?

**2-** Can I use all puppeteer documentations inside APify , or they have some restrictions ?

**3-** What's difference between Pure Puppeteer & Apify's Puppeteer ?

### **(*) Half-Solution :**

For **Question 1** , I tried this solution , I worked with Pure Puppeteer , I go to first page , click the next button , get its url , go again to the next page , get its url , and so on , till the finish of while loop . After that I copy paste the url in txt file , and I upload it to start urls.

This is the code source I tried :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    

    const url ="https://www.google.com/travel/hotels/Marrakesh?utm_campaign=sharing&utm_medium=link&utm_source=htls&hrf=CgUIzAgQACIDTUFEKhYKBwjkDxAIGBkSBwjkDxAIGBoYASABsAEAWAFoAYoBKAoSCcxMCO-rXT9AEQMTl9GnSCDAEhIJVRwqc-jwP0ARByaebVl8HsCaATESCU1hcnJha2VzaBokMHhkYWZlZThkOTYxNzllNTE6MHg1OTUwYjY1MzRmODdhZGI4ogEVCggvbS8wNTRydxIJTWFycmFrZXNoqgEbCgIIIRICCAgSAggVEgMIlAISAggvEgIIVBgBqgEHCgMIoQIYAKoBDAoDCLYBEgMIuAEYAaoBBgoCCGQYAKoBCgoCCC4SAghIGAGqAQwKAwiuARIDCLQBGAGqAQoKAghQEgIITxgBqgEMCgMIowESAwimARgBkgECIAE&rp=OAE&ap=KigKEgnMTAjvq10_QBEDE5fRp0ggwBISCVUcKnPo8D9AEQcmnm1ZfB7AMAFanwIKBQjMCBAAIgNNQUQqFgoHCOQPEAgYEhIHCOQPEAgYExgBKACwAQBYAWgBigEoChIJzEwI76tdP0ARAxOX0adIIMASEglVHCpz6PA_QBEHJp5tWXwewJoBMRIJTWFycmFrZXNoGiQweGRhZmVlOGQ5NjE3OWU1MToweDU5NTBiNjUzNGY4N2FkYjiiARUKCC9tLzA1NHJ3EglNYXJyYWtlc2iqARsKAgghEgIICBICCBUSAwiUAhICCC8SAghUGAGqAQcKAwihAhgAqgEMCgMItgESAwi4ARgBqgEGCgIIZBgAqgEKCgIILhICCEgYAaoBDAoDCK4BEgMItAEYAaoBCgoCCFASAghPGAGqAQwKAwijARIDCKYBGAGSAQIgAQ"
    await page.goto(url,{
        waitUntil: 'load',
        // Remove the timeout
        timeout: 0});

  
    //for(i=0;i<10;i+)
    console.log(url);
    console.log('\n');
    while(true){
        await page.click('div.zbLWdb');
        await page.waitFor(30*1000);
        var new_link = page.url();
        
        console.log(new_link);
        console.log('\n\n');
        i++;
    }

    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

**Can I put this script in starts urls & How to do this ?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna give you all details for scraping it successfully but will give you a few hints.

a) It is important to get the names correct. In this case, you are using [Puppeteer Scraper](https://apify.com/apify/puppeteer-scraper). That is a standalone actor. [PuppeteerCrawler](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteer-crawler) is a class in the SDK (JS library).

b) The link selector will not click, it needs to find hrefs (real links). So it won't work for this use-case.

c) In this case, I would suggest creating a new actor with the PuppeteerCrawler class (see examples in the [SDK](https://sdk.apify.com/) site).

Now to answer your questions:

1. You can use your code inside Apify and it will work the same. More advanced solution that will allow you to split the load into more requests is using [`enqueueLinksByClickingElements`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteer#puppeteerenqueuelinksbyclickingelementsoptions) to enqueue next pages. But I'm not 100% sure it will work correctly for this use-case.
2. It is the same Puppeteer instance so no restrictions. Apify depends on the `puppeteer` package.
3. The only big difference is that Apify makes it simple to use authenticated proxy in Puppeteer, otherwise, it is the same. Of course, PuppeteerCrawler gives you a ton of functionality like autoscaling concurrency, retrying, proxy rotation, sessions, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much to your response. in fact , I try to use enqueueLinksByClickingElements() methods , but didn't work , I take the correct selector , but without any good answer .

Comment: can I use pptr method (page.url() , page.click()  ) then write a function , and swap it with enqueueLinksByClickingElements() method , or I have to get stuck with this method ?

Comment: If it doesn't work for whatever reason, I would probably keep it on a single page with page.click(). Of course, you can re-implement everything yourself.